# r data.table summarizing using more than one factor

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, aggregate, plyr

i have below data.table

```
'data.frame':   66977 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ SUBS                         : int  
 $ CITY                         : Factor w/ 18 levels 
 $ VALUE_SEG                    : Factor w/ 7 levels 
 $ region                       : Factor w/ 5 levels 
 $ SUM.DATA_PPU_REV_DEC.        : num  
 $ SUM.DATA_BUNDLE_REV_DEC.     : int  
 $ SUM.DATA_USAGE_TOTAL_KB_DEC. : num  
 $ SUM.THIS_MONTH_REV_DEC.      : num  
 $ SUM.VOICE_ONNET_DURATION_DEC.: num  
 $ SUM.VOICE_ONNET_REV_DEC.     : num  
 $ SUM.VOICE_OFFNET_REV_DEC.    : num  
 $ SUM.SMS_ONNET_REV_DEC.       : num  
 $ SUM.SMS_OFFNET_REV_DEC.      : int  
 $ SUM.RECHARGE_DEC.            : int  
 $ STATUS_DEC                   : Factor w/ 5 levels 
 $ TYPE_DEC_2                   : Factor w/ 6 levels
```

i want to group it by two of the Factor variables let's say VALUE_SEG & region, get the sum for number and create new coulm for each factor variable with count of observations. i tryied aggregate, ddply and others with varians type of errors :( thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to separate numeric and factor variable and summarize using `dplyr`. It could be like

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% select(VALUE_SEG,region,SUM..... all numeric variables) %>% 
   group_by(VALUE_SEG,region) %>% summarize_each(funs(sum)) -> summary1

## For factors

data %>% select(VALUE_SEG,region,SUM..... all factors variables) %>% 
   group_by(VALUE_SEG,region) %>% summarize_each(funs(n)) -> summary2

## Then you can merge these results

Summary <- merge(summary1,summary2,by="VALUE_SEG")
```

For more details on using this package visit this [link](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/11068_8bc42d6df61341b2bed45e9a9a3bf9f4.html)

Comment: thanks @koundy, i tried your recommendation but i got below error                 Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: did u just run this code? in `select(..)` function you should write all numeric/factor column names. if u can provide a reproducible example it would be better to check.

Comment: my mistake, i ammended by sub.nov %>% select(VALUE_SEG, region, SUBS + SUM.DATA_PPU_REV_NOV., SUM.DATA_BUNDLE_REV_NOV., SUM.DATA_USAGE_TOTAL_KB_NOV. , SUM.THIS_MONTH_REV_NOV., SUM.VOICE_ONNET_DURATION_NOV., SUM.VOICE_ONNET_REV_NOV., SUM.VOICE_OFFNET_REV_NOV., SUM.SMS_ONNET_REV_NOV., SUM.SMS_OFFNET_REV_NOV., SUM.RECHARGE_NOV.) %>% 
  group_by(VALUE_SEG,region) %>% summarise(sum) -> summary1  but got below error in summarise ------ Error: not a vector.. appreciate your support

Comment: its not `summarise`. its `summarize_each(funs(sum))` to summarize all columns

Comment: Error in function_list[[k]](value) : 
  could not find function "summarize_each"

Comment: `summarise_each` check spelling

Comment: one last favor, in the second part the summery for the factores i need to create 6 coulomns each contain sum of observations of the TYPE_NOV_2 i tried summarise(weekly=n(TYPE_DEC_2=="Weekly"))   but not working.

Comment: instead of summarise try `count(colnames)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sum(x) else .N),
                          by= list(VALUE_SEG,region)]
```